# Play Services Locatio v21.0.0 - cannot be cast to ResolvableApiException

Tags: android, android-location, google-location-services

I updated Google Play Services Location from

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0"`

to

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0"`

and now the following code doesn't work to enable location on the device:

```
    LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity)
        .checkLocationSettings(settingsBuilder.build())
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            try {
                task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            } catch (ex: ApiException) {
                when (ex.statusCode) {
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> try {
                        val resolvableApiException =
                            ex as ResolvableApiException
```

Error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need `21.0.0` I would suggest using the `20.0.0`, as noted in release notes for it.

> Warning: This release of play-services-location (v21.0.0) has a known
> issue that can break SettingsClient APIs. We strongly recommend
> avoiding this version.

It's a breaking change/thing on Googles part - [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256046114)